# Php header location working but not redirect

Tags: php

Hi I use this code I sending data with ajax and I use music site for location when I use this php music site working I hear sound but browser don't redirect I don't understand realy.Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please, do your home work.

Comment: I'm trying.you're just talking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a problem.

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com");    
echo "Mesaj";    
exit;
```

You are sending content right after you decide to redirect.

Here is what you should do:

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/?m=Mesaj"); 
exit;
```

Comment: well do you get An Error? if not add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` on top of your code, and show us the error

Comment: I have found.Thank you for your interest in

Comment: maybe you can post your solution to help future visitors

Answer (score 0):

Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a **file**, or from PHP.